# I want to retrieve data of user having same profession attribute from firebase table

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

As in my table user having the same profession=doctor.

I want to select all users having the same profession and want to show them in recycler view.

Comment: You must use a `for` loop to read all profession nodes from each UID, then use an `if (profession.equals("doctor")` statement to show them in the recycler

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get all the users that a profession set as a doctor, you need to see a Query. So please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
Query queryByProffesion = usersRef.orderByChild("proffesion").equalTo("doctor");
    queryByProffesion.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, name);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be the name of all users who are doctors. For displaying the results in a RecyclerView, please check my answer from the following post:

- [How can I retrieve data from Firebase to my adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)

Comment: Hi Alex,Sir i tried but it didnt work for me kindly if you help me out

Comment: What exactly didn't help? Without seeing the code, I cannot be much of a help. Please edit your question and add your code, and tell what exactly doesn't work.